# How to best create an xml map of recursive directory listing in rubyonrails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby

I want to build an XML map of all directories and files in my public/catalogs rails directory.(recursive map)

I would like it to be constructed with basic `<directory> <file>` element with name attribute equal to the dir or file name.

```
<catalogs>
 <file name="index.html">
 <directory name="foo">
    <file name="file1.html" />
    <directory name="bar">
       <file name="file2.html" />
    </directory>
 </directory>
</catalogs>
```

I am just not sure what the best way to do recursive map to xml - I looked for a plugin that might handle this since it seems like it something someone might have though to construct.

Any thoughts or direction on best way to create this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I never found a plugin or any thing that seems to be built to do this... so I had to roll my own... here it is complete with attributes for sha and url since I needed them. Hope this helps someone else.

```
xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent => 2,:escape_attrs => true)
xml.instruct!    
xml.catalogs(:version=>2) {list_entries("#{CATALOG_PATH}", xml)}
File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/catalogs.xml", 'w') {|f| f.write(xml.target!) }

def list_entries(dir,xml)
  Dir.glob("#{dir}/*") do |entry|
    if File::directory?(entry)
      xml.directory(:name=>File.basename(entry)) {
        list_entries(entry, xml)
      }
    else
      xml.file(:name=>File.basename(entry),:sha => Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(entry),
      :url=>entry.gsub("#{CATALOG_PATH}","#{CATALOG_URL}"))
    end
  end
end
```